# Powershell: Supress or Hide Browser during invoke-webrequest

Tags: powershell

I have a script that makes a request to download some files. The site uses certificate authentication so when I request the file (`Invoke-WebRequest`) it will return a form that I have to send back to the action url using `Invoke-RestMethod`. The code below works but it opens a new IExplorer instance to parse the form out of the response for every single call to `$response.forms["form"]`. This really causes a problem when I am looping over this code and requesting a lot of files. Is there a way to suppress IE? Something like $IE.visible = $false?

I should mention I tried to use the `-UseBasicParsing` option and tried to build the FormObject from `$response.InputFields` but I was not able to figure out how to create a FormObject in Powershell. I know how the object should be laid out if anyone can guide me on creating a `FormObject` that would help too.

Thanks!

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $url -Certificate $cert
Invoke-RestMethod -uri $form_action_url -body $response.forms["form"] -method Post -OutFile $file
```

Comment: kizyle502, did you find a solution?  If you don't mind, please see my version of this problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166426/